# FlowDocumentPage viewer enable scroll content in touch screen

Tags: c#, wpf

I have FlowDocumentPage viewer for view in touch screen how to enable scroll it is content without enable zooming in it

this the code i used

```
                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type FlowDocumentPageViewer}">

                                <AdornerDecorator>

                                    <DocumentPageView ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" FlowDocumentPageViewer.IsMasterPage="True" />

                                </AdornerDecorator>

                            </ControlTemplate>

                        </FlowDocumentPageViewer.Template>

                        <FlowDocument Name="fd" ColumnWidth="1000"   >
                        </FlowDocument>

                    </FlowDocumentPageViewer>
```

Comment: Did you try it with [`FlowDocumentReader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentreader(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`FlowDocumentScrollViewer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.flowdocumentscrollviewer(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `FlowDocumentPageViewer`?

Comment: FlowDocumentReader didn't read any content